# Converges of composition of two complex functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

if $g$ is a continuous function defined on a bounded domain, suppose $f_{n}$ be a sequence of functions defined on the same domain and uniformly convergent to f then is it possible to say that $g(f_{n})$ will be uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ is uniformly continuous, it will certainly be true. I doubt you can generally conclude uniform convergence unless you have that assumption on $g$, but I am not completely sure. Here is a proof for the case where $g$ is uniformly continuous:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\eta > 0$ such that for all $x, y$

$$|x-y| < \eta \implies |g(x)-g(y)| < \epsilon.$$

Now, since $f_n$ converges uniformly, we may choose $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \eta $$

for all $x$. But then for all $n \geq N$ we have

$$|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))| < \epsilon,$$

for all $x$, which shows that $g \circ f_n$ converges uniformly to $g \circ f$.

I have omitted the domains of these functions since the question is unclear as to this, but I trust the reader will be able to adjust the argument to fit the domains in question.